# Making CSS appearance work properly in older iPads (and other browsers)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, css

The css property `appearance` lets you change radio buttons with custom images. This is quite useful for a product with different variations, for example, as the user can tap/click on an image of variation rather than a radio button.

However, it doesn't work properly on the original iPad (even when using  `-webkit-appearance`), as some of the images come out the wrong size.

It also doesn't work in Firefox.

I was wondering if there are any jquery/javascript plug ins to make them work properly.

I know that there is [unifrom.js](http://uniformjs.com/) and [Ryan Fait's script](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/) that let you swap radio buttons and images, but these involve creating spans and not as elegant as `appearance`.

I have [read about hacks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/#comment-172346) to make appearance  work, but cannot find any links on how to implement them.

Hopefully, there is something to force appearance to work properly (just like there are scripts to force older browsers to recognize HTML5 tags).

PS. My site requires Javascript to work, so I am not worried about users who have JS turned off. It's also a tablet specific version, so I am not too concerned about IE users.

Comment: there is a good reason plugins were created to replace readios and checkboxes. You can't do much with them in older browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no good way to reliably style Radio buttons across borders. There is, however, a quite simple solution that doesn't use javascript:

```
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

input[type=radio] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

label {
  padding-left: 48px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font: normal 38px/130% sans-serif;
  background: transparent url(http://www.screwdefaultbuttons.com/images/radio.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  background-position: 0 -43px;
}
```

​Clicking on a label checks it's corresponding input radio. This, in turn, changes the label's background image, so you can customize radio buttons with images without javascript.

You can see a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/wa2Gz/

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Here are some tips that might help people with the same problem. 1. For older ipads, `onclick=""` must be added to the label, otherwise the label wont sync with the radio button. There's a good thread about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162576/block-style-radio-buttons-working-on-everything-but-ipad    2. Properties like `background-sizing` might not work on older tablets if entered in as shorthand, if inherited  or if entered without a vendor prefix. 3. On Android, the label method only seems to work with android 3.0 and later.